# SSRS Sharepoint List IIF Field Value = "area 1" then add 60 days to date value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I hope someone can assist or point me in the right direction

I have a report that contains Fields!District.Value, If this value = "area 1" then i would like to add 60 days to the Field!Date.Value

Obligatory "I'm still learning" SSRS and I have tried the following with no success;

=IIf(Fields!District.Value="North Lanarkshire","DateAdd("d", 60, Fields!Date.Value)"

I'm assuming it's placement of a , or )

thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of mistake here. Let's break it down.

To start with the IIF function syntax can be thought of like this..

```
IIF([Expression to evaluate to true or false], [expression to return if true], [expression to return if false])
```

So your first expression `Fields!District.Value="North Lanarkshire"` is fine, this will return true or false.

Next expression, what to return if true is close but not correct. `"DateAdd("d", 60, Fields!Date.Value)"`. There is no need for the outer quotes and instead of "d" you should use `DateInterval.Day` so this should end up being `DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 60, Fields!Date.Value)`.

Finally we need something to return if the result is false (i.e. District is not "North Lanarkshire"). I'll assume you just want the original date column's value returned here so we can just use `Fields!Date.Value`

So, the final expression should look like this.

```
=IIF(Fields!District.Value="North Lanarkshire", DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 60, Fields!Date.Value), Fields!Date.Value)
```

Comment: Great this has worked perfectly! Many thanks for the clear breakdown and explanation Alan, appreciate the assist.